# Mysql Equivalent in ElasticSearch, Updating a field based on a field

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I'm having an index named 'books'. In that, Title & Author name are two fields with string type.I need to create a new field, such that it won't contain Author name in the Title.

For Example :

Title : Advanced Scoring in ES by James Gindal

Author Name : James Gindal

then, New_field = Advanced Scoring in ES by.

In mysql I can do an update query by simple string REPLACE() function. Need a working solution in ES.

Answer (score 0):

use painless script using [_update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

```
{
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.new_field = 'Advanced Scoring in ES by'",
        "lang": "painless"
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "Advanced Scoring in ES by James Gindal"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "author_name": {
                            "value": "James Gindal"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is too specific to that record. I need to do it for all the records in that index.